# How to filter aspnet core logs?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-2.0

The following boilerplate, Microsoft-provided C# code for ASP.NET Core 2.1 should prevent merely informational logs from being written. But it doesn't.

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning))
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I still see messages like:

> MyApp> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker[2]

and

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action /Index in 11.2286ms

I have deliberately removed (for now) the code to call AppSettings.json. Why am I still seeing information-severity log items?

Comment: I was able to filter the error logs out by adding a filter `logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.None);` its a possible solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0#log-filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following change in your code, set the category of the first AddFilter is null

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddFilter(null, LogLevel.Warning);

            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning));
```

Add logWarning to test in Home/Index

```
 private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Log Information");
        _logger.LogWarning("Log Warning");
    }
```

The screenshot of result

[image]

Comment: Great code, very clear. It looks as though we can only suppress (filter) log items that would  be created in our own code. I was hoping to prevent the informational log items that VS generates as my code runs. Warnings and worse, fine, but not all the others.

Comment: I am also struggling with the same thing.  Can't get rid of those microsoft/system logs.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked using the AddFilter<>() generic method (I'm working with ASP.Net Core 3.1). I'm logging to the windows event log and I just want warnings and errors going there.
So, I added a filter to the EventLogLoggerProvider to only log warnings from "Microsoft" category.

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings =>
            {
                eventLogSettings.LogName = Constants.Service.EventLogName;
                eventLogSettings.SourceName = Constants.Service.EventSourceName;
            });
            logging.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change it without changing your code, here is your solution [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging)